# Query LIKE in mongoDB as SQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I would like to find records with username LIKE '%abc%' using mongoDB syntax via Sails model native. How to do my issue?

Comment: I get a param called "key", and I need to push the value of "key" into regex string. I think it is impossible, so that I ask this question for other ideas.

Comment: How about showing what you have tried? Or perhaps `var query={ "field": { "$regex": key } }` Which is basically `LIKE '%key%'` with variable substitution of course.

Comment: Hehe, I think I tried less. Your ex is great. Thanks a lot!